# Getting the last 3 letters in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice

An example be like:

```
def get_last_three_letters(a_list):
    for name in a_list:
        name = name[-3:].lower()

    return name

def main():
   print("1.", get_last_three_letters(["Jess", "Cain", "Amity", "Raeann"]))
   print("2.", get_last_three_letters(["CAIn", "JessiE", "O", "ROBERT", 
   "Geoffrey", "Li", "B"]))
   print("3.", "***" + get_last_three_letters([]) + "***")
   print("4.", "***" + get_last_three_letters(["A", "E", "O"]) + "***")
```

my output like:

```
 1. ann
 2. b
```

I'm trying to get the last 3 characters from a string,I expect to get the output like:

```
 1. essainityann
 2. ainsieertrey
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you're overwriting `names` at each iteration. Instead, keep a list, and *`append`* those values, and finally `str.join` them and return.

```
def get_last_three_letters(a_list):
    tails = []
    for name in a_list:
        if len(name) > 2:
            tails.append(name[-3:].lower())

    return ''.join(tails)
```

You can shorten this to a list comprehension, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536107/4909087) mentions.

```
def get_last_three_letters(a_list):
    return ''.join([x[-3:].lower() for x in a_list if len(x) > 2])
```

<sub>Note that passing a list to `str.join` is actually faster than a generator comprehension!</sub>

---

```
>>> get_last_three_letters(["Jess", "Cain", "Amity", "Raeann"])
'essainityann'
>>> get_last_three_letters(["CAIn", "JessiE", "O", "ROBERT", "Geoffrey", "Li", "B"])
'ainsieertrey'
```

Comment: @Kee Well it is now.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough to do the trick:

```
def get_last_three_chars(my_list):
    return ''.join(x[-3:].lower() for x in my_list if len(x) >= 3)
```

---

```
>>> get_last_three_chars(["Jess", "Cain", "Amity", "Raeann"])
'essainityann'
>>> get_last_three_chars(["CAIn", "JessiE", "O", "ROBERT", "Geoffrey", "Li", "B"])
'ainsieertrey'
```